# Nginx Docker container [as part of Laradock] returning 'ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED'

Tags: php, laravel, docker, nginx, laradock

I'm stuck trying to get an existing Laravel project running using Docker / Laradock.

I used the instructions on https://laradock.io/ and use the following command to start the containers:

```
docker-compose up -d nginx mysql phpmyadmin redis workspace
```

My containers are up and running:

[image]

But any variant of localhost (127.0.0.1 etc.) returns this:

```
This site can’t be reached 
localhost unexpectedly closed the connection.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

I tried getting some logs using `docker logs laradock_nginx_1` but there's nothing to see there.

I didn't change the `docker-compose.yml` provided by Laradock.io. This is it:
https://www.codepile.net/pile/p6RQlE5W

I didn't change the Dockerfile either, here's the one for nginx:
https://www.codepile.net/pile/JVRZYNVB

Where to look?

Comment: Show your `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile`'s pls

Comment: Also, have you completed the 4th step? `4 - Open your project’s .env file and set the following:

DB_HOST=mysql
REDIS_HOST=redis
QUEUE_HOST=beanstalkd`

Comment: @Yasen docker-compose and Dockerfile added to my question (didn't edit them). And yes, I completed step 4.

Comment: `nginx` code is empty: https://www.codepile.net/pile/92RwpWgY

Comment: @Yasen Fixed now (new link).

Answer (score 0):

## Use correct folder to your php-project directory

According to [documentation](https://laradock.io/getting-started/#A1), your php-project should be placed near the `laradock` folder.

E.g.:

### Folder structure for multiply projects:

> 2 - Make sure your folder structure should look like this:
>
> - project-a
>
>   - laradock-a
> - project-b
>
>   - laradock-b

### Folder structure for the only project:

> 2 - Make sure your folder structure should look like this:
>
> - project-a
>
>   - laradock-a
> - project-b
>
>   - laradock-b

## Set `APP_CODE_PATH_HOST` in the `.env` config file

[2. Getting Started - Laradock](https://laradock.io/getting-started/#A1):

> 2 - Edit your web server sites configuration.
>   We’ll need to do step 1 of the [Usage](https://laradock.io/getting-started/#Usage) section now to make this happen.
>
> ```
> cp env-example .env
> ```
>
> At the top, change the `APP_CODE_PATH_HOST` variable to your project path.
>
> ```
> APP_CODE_PATH_HOST=../project-z/
> ```
>
> Make sure to replace `project-z` with your project folder name.
>
> 3 - Go to the [Usage](https://laradock.io/getting-started/#Usage) section.

Comment: No luck just yet. APP_CODE_PATH_HOST should be ../ (as it is now) because the laradock folder is inside the project folder. I followed the instructions in the Usage section but same result ..

Comment: Seems, there is an issue #107 like yours: [This site can’t be reached · Issue #107 · laradock/laradock](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/107). Unfortunately, it was closed without any explanations. by one of laradock's members.